# SAML error for SSO with ADFS using passport-SAML express

Tags: xml, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs, passport-saml

Hi I am trying to use SSO to authenticate my client's users directly to my website. My client's IDP is Microsoft ADFS and I am using Passport-SAML (https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml) to configure the SSO process.

I am getting the following error in client's ADFS server log when I try to login:

**"The Federation Service encountered an error while processing the SAML authentication request"**

and in Exception details:

**"MSIS0038: SAML message has wrong signature. issuer:'myCompany_com'."**

Here the process I followed:

1/ Got my medatafile myCompany.xml using passport script and provide it to my client

2/ My client add it in **Add Relying Party Trust** in his ADFS, add rules using the **Send LDAP Attributes as Claims** template and add another rules using **Transform an incoming Claim option** and send me his Certificate

Error flow:
1/ User access authentication area from myClient (in fact got redirect there after using the following URL: www.myClientSpace.myCompany.com
2/ Enter his credential and try to sign in, then the error appear in ADFS SERVER LOG
Maybe I'm missing something in my XML file...

**Thanks for your time & help!!!**

PS: here my XML file

```
<EntityDescriptor entityID="myCompany_com" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>MIICQ...</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://www.myCompany.com/adfs/postResponse/logout"/>
    <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://www.myCompany.com/adfs/postResponse/postResponse" index="0"/>
  </SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is either something wrong with the certificate e.g. that is not the one you are using to sign or there was an error importing into ADFS.

The other possible reason is that you are not signing the AuthnRequest and ADFS is expecting you to,

Comment: Thanks you for answering. How can I check if ADFS is expecting to sign AuthnRequest?

Comment: PowerShell - Get-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust - -SignedSamlRequestsRequired.